# How to serve files in Django without "/static" prefix

Tags: django, angular, django-staticfiles

I have an angular 2 front-end with already written links between html js, css and other files such as images, that I would like to serve using Django.

The structure from Angular 2 looks like following:

```
-->index.html
-->test.js
-->test.css
```

HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
<body>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js">
</body>
```

I wouldn't like to change the given paths from the angular 2 app, instead I would like to know the workaround to serve this files in django without using "/static/< appname>/" or "/static/" prefix or template tags in every link.

## Update

Trying to avoid

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <link href="/static/test.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
<body>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/test.js">
</body>
```

and avoiding this:

```
{% load static %} <link href="{% static "example.jpg" %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

In other words, trying to adapt django builtin webserver to serve angular files without adapting ("static" prefix or tag) them to django.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The right way to serve static files is not hardcoded is like: `{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>`. What do you mean when you talk avout to avoid `/static` Post an example.

Comment: @danihp thank you for comment. I just updated the question with examples.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to "serve your files" from Django, but I think you really want to serve them from something like Nginx.  For example,

```
location = /js/test.js {
    root /path/to/js/;
}
```

in your nginx file.  For the purposes of Angular2 URLs, you can pretend that Django doesn't exist.

Comment: thank you. I thought about it too. But it would be nice if I could also serve the angular app with the django builtin webserver. Do you know how to tweak the django to avoid prefixing or tagging with static?

Comment: You could create a view and then use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse to read the files and send the raw HTTP output to the browser.  But I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Hangon the built in webserver is fine for testing and development but it is not recommended as a long-term solution for a live deployment. It's up to you to decide whether that's a problem for your project or not.